# Как называется такое предложение?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Как называется такое предложение? В нём же и сложноподчинённое, и сложносочинённое есть.

> Я хотела съездить на дачу цветы полить, но потом вспомнила, что дома ключом шкаф не закрыла второпях.

Comment: Это СПП,  в главном предложении сочинительная связь между однородными сказуемыми: хотела съездить, но вспомнила,